# Application design for using a dynamic Navigation menu with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a small Web MVC application which currently has a controller that takes 4 requests:

```
GET / : main.jsp 
GET /year/month  : showItems.jsp 
GET /add  : ostItem.jsp 
POST /add  : successItem.jsp
```

Every .jsp pages includes a header.html and a footer.html

Now my problem is that I have a dynamic Navigation menu which needs to be populated in my header.html. With dynamic I mean that the content of the navigation menu is based on data in my database (in this case: it takes all year/month combinations which are stored in the database).

So in my controller, for every method listed above I have to populate my Model object with an attribute "navigation" which includes the links and navigation names.

If I only have 4 requests to handle it is OK. But what if an application grows to 100 requests? It really seems bad design to have to populate the navigation menu over and over again in every request.

One thing I could do is return the menu through another request in JSON and populate it that way, but that seems to kind of differ from my current design (some requests return a .jsp page with a model, some requests return JSON, it can get messy pretty fast!)

Comment: Use a template system like thymeleaf. Also, retrieve the data from database periodically and store it in a cache, probably `ServletContext` or a real cache like ehcache or infinispan, then build your menu based on the data stored in cache rather than accessing to database every time.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the template idea later today.